# Raspberry Pi isc-dhcp-server: No subnet declaration for eth0

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, dhcp, subnet

I am trying to set up a DHCP server on my Raspberry Pi. I tried installing it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

And the following log is shown:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
   icelib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 302 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/887 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 61701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace isc-dhcp-server 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6 (using .../isc-dhcp-server_4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6_armhf.deb) ...
[FAIL] Stopping ISC DHCP server: dhcpd failed!
Unpacking replacement isc-dhcp-server ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6) ...
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
```

When I open the /var/log/syslog file, it shows the following lines:

```
No subnet declaration for th0 (x.x.x.x)
** Ignoring requests on eth0. If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration 
   In your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface eth0 is attached. **
```

I am new to linux so I don't know what is wrong with my system or where to go from here.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for [SO]. Vote to close

Comment: @talonmies can you explain why is off-topic? What would make it on-topic?

Comment: @rhermans: Nothing would make it on-topic. Instructions for setting up the DHCP server on a raspberry-pi is about as directly programming related as instructions for building an IKEA flat pack computer desk.

Answer (score 3):

As root, issue:

```
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

to install the server.

Then the server can be configured using the config file located at `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True. I have moved the most relevant info from the linked-to pdf into the actual answer. Thanks.

Comment: A formerly-link-only answer that's been salvaged by its author? What sorcery is this?

Comment: Salvaged answer or not, the question is still blatantly off-topic.